# Rails has_many with alias name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

In my User model I could have:

```
has_many :tasks
```

and in my Task model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Then, supposing the foreign key 'user_id' was stored in the tasks table, I could use:

```
@user.tasks
```

---

My question is, how do I declare the has_many relationship such that I can refer to a User's Tasks as:

```
@user.jobs
```

... or ...

```
@user.foobars
```

Thanks a heap.

Comment: I'd be weary of using Task as a class name - it is a Rails reserved word and might cause strange issues down the road: http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 418, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```ruby
has_many :jobs, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'Task'
```

Note, that `:as` is used for [polymorphic associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Also, [foreign_key option for has_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-foreign-key).

Comment: Thank you for also including the foreign key - solved my similar but different problem.

Comment: Does this need anything special on the Task side or is the usual `belongs_to` sufficient?

Comment: FYI: this also works for has_and_belongs_to_many associations, only no need for the "foreign_key" piece

Comment: how to you query this if i need a string to be matched

Answer (score 77):

You could also use `alias_attribute` if you still want to be able to refer to them as tasks as well:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :jobs, :tasks

  has_many :tasks
end
```

Comment: Note that the `alias_attribute` call must come before associations.

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 20):

If you use has_many through, and want to alias:

```
has_many :alias_name, through: :model_name, source: :initial_name
```

(thanks for the correction Sami Birnbaum)

Comment: Just for clarity, the `model_name` and `initial_name` should be a symbol like this `:model_name` and `:initial_name`

Answer (score 4):

To complete @SamSaffron's answer :

You can use `class_name` with either `foreign_key` or `inverse_of`. I personally prefer the more abstract declarative, but it's really just a matter of taste :

```
class BlogPost
  has_many :images, class_name: "BlogPostImage", inverse_of: :blog_post  
end
```

and you need to make sure you have the `belongs_to` attribute on the child model:

```
class BlogPostImage
  belongs_to :blog_post
end
```