# rails, how to alias a relation in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to override the name of a relation, here is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :class_rooms_member_ships

  has_many :class_rooms
  has_many :class_rooms, :through=> :class_rooms_member_ships

end
```

now, I need another name to use when I want to get `class_rooms :through=> :class_rooms_member_ships`

how can I achieve this:

```
user.class_rooms
user.class_rooms_through
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163032/rails-has-many-with-alias-name?

Comment: but, my case is a little bit different, I am using has_many through

Comment: The question's title is misleading in a way. Strictly speaking you are not asking for an alias as stated in the question. Because that would mean that the association would still have to be accessible by its original name. Instead you are asking for a way to define the name of the association. The answer for the question in the title is probably `alias_attribute`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
has_many :classrooms_though_memberships, :through=> :class_rooms_member_ships, 
                                     :class_name => 'ClassRoom', 
                                     :foreign_key => 'class_room_id',
                                     :source => :class_room
```

This should work.

Comment: exactly, it worked fine, it seems that the source was missing, thanks

Comment: `class_name` and `foreign_key` should not be necessary, `source` specifies the relation name.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
has_many :classrooms_though_memberships, :through=> :class_rooms_member_ships, 
                                         :class_name => 'ClassRoom', 
                                         :foreign_key => 'class_room_id'
```

Comment: I tried it, but, I've got this error:

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError in ClassRoomsMemberShipsController#index

Could not find the source association(s) :classrooms_though_membership or :classrooms_though_memberships in model ClassRoomsMemberShip. Try 'has_many :classrooms_though_memberships, :through => :class_rooms_member_ships, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?