# How do I have multiple has_many to has_many relationship between two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I'm newer to Rails and have a problem with a model that has multiple relationships to another model. This is my current setup, and I can add events to the user through the UserEvents model.  However, obviously I can't have the relationship called events twice...and this is where I am stumped.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events, :through => :user_events
  has_many :events, :through => :user_participating
end

class UserEvents < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserParticipating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end

class Events < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_event
  has_one :user, :through => :user_events
  has_many :user_participating
  has_many :user, :through => :user_participating
end
```

There is definitely a good chance I am going about this all wrong, however, I have been at it for several hours and I don't seem to be getting anywhere.  So, I figured I would ask.  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163032/rails-has-many-with-alias-name).  Essentially, you can set up multiple associations (with different names) between the same two classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :user_participatings
  has_many :events, through: :user_events
  has_many :participating_events, through: :user_participatings, class_name: 'Event'
end

class UserEvents < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end

class UserParticipating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end

class Events < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_event
  has_one :user, through: :user_events
  has_many :user_participatings
  has_many :participants, through: :user_participatings, source: :user
end
```

Even if I notice an event `has_one` user so I don't see why you need the `UserEvent` class

Comment: Am I able to change the has_many relation in Events from users to participants?

Comment: Yes, name it :participants and add class_name: 'User'

Comment: I ended up having to also add `source: :user` but it worked!  Thanks!