# Create associations to the same model multiple times - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a rather weird case. I have a few models that are tied together via associations one of these associations allows the user model to access referenced job data directly with the job model. However, the second case allows the user model to access the job data via the locations model.

```
User has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
User has_many :jobs through: :locations
```

So how do I need to distinguish these two lines of code so that `User.jobs` uses the first association and `User.jobs_through_locations` uses the second association?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163032/rails-has-many-with-alias-name) what you're looking for?

Comment: @wolfson I tried that but couldn't get it to work most likely because of the many-to-many association. I would think something like that would work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom association name for the second association and use that name for referencing the jobs from third table.

Note: source is important as you need to tell rails which model to use when fetching user_jobs.

**User**

has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs

has_many :user_jobs, through: :locations, :source => :jobs

Answer (score 0):

If Locations has many jobs, give the second association a different name and tell it which association in Location is the source.

```
User has_many :jobs_through_locations, through: :locations, source: 
:jobs
```